# VueJS Slot v-text

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I want to show a variable in the default scope. This version works.

```
<slot>{{namedSlotText}}</slot>
```

But when I try it this other way, the variable doesn't show.

**Template**

```
<div id="app">
  <my-component></my-component>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
let vm = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  components:{    
    myComponent:{
      template:`
        <div>
         <slot :text="namedSlotText"></slot>
        </div>
      `,
      data:()=>({
        namedSlotText: "This is default slot text"
      })
    }
  }
})
```

I saw some places where `v-text` works.

Comment: Slot is out of scope. Data is only accessable within #app el.

Comment: My data function inside myComponent and data is not accesible in #app only accesible myComponent inside

Answer (score 2):

When you pass a property to a `slot`, essentially you are making data available to be used by the content of the slot. The concept is called [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots).

This code

```
<div>
  <slot :text="namedSlotText"></slot>
</div>
```

is *only* making the `text` property available to be used by the content of the slot. In order to *use* that property, you have to first define a scoped template and then explicitly reference the property in the content.

```
<my-component>
  <template scope="{text}">
    {{text}}
  </template>
</my-component>
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using an arrow functions for data, the correct ES2015 syntax (inside components) is:

```
data() {
  return {
    namedSlotText: "This is default slot text"
  }
}
```

Because you are using a standard slot you can set the default value like so:

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
  template: `<div><slot>{{slotText}}</slot></div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      slotText: "This is default slot text"
    }
  }
})
```

Here's the JSFIddle: https://jsfiddle.net/va438nqk/

Comment: No,I think probably problem is not understood,You tell in answer change data method but  i said in my question  <slot>{{namedSlotText}}</slot> is work but <slot :text="namedSlotText"></slot> not work This mean it's not data problem and if data is inside components is must be function

Comment: Ah I see what you are trying to do, I missed that you were using a component. You are just using a standard slot, so you can set default values by placing text between your slot: https://jsfiddle.net/va438nqk/

Comment: Yeah i know that I asked why look like that example https://jsfiddle.net/tL88259x/  is not work?

Comment: I think you're getting mixed up with [scoped slots](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots)